# pyspark-connect can't show all hive databases

Tags: pyspark, hive, hadoop3, spark-connect

I'm using pyspark3.4.0 feature spark-connet module to connect remote hive 3.1.3.

When create sparksession in local mode with hive supported, all data base in hive can be viewed;

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().master("local").getOrCreate()
spark.sql("show databases")
```

But, when I tried to use spark-connect, only default database was showed.

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().remote("sc://localhost:15002").getOrCreate()
spark.sql("show databases")
```

I'm expected it show all the databases,so as to select/add data.

I have copied 'hive-site.xml' to $SPARK_HOME/conf.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons for `'pyspark-connect'` not displaying all Hive databases in PySpark. Here are a few possible issues that you might need to check:

**Permissions:** The user account being used to connect to `Hive` may not have sufficient permissions to access all the databases. Ensure that the user has the necessary privileges to view all the databases.

**Configuration:** Verify the configuration settings for connecting to Hive in 'pyspark-connect'. Ensure that the correct Hive metastore `URI` and other relevant properties are configured properly.

**Hive metastore synchronization:** It's possible that the Hive metastore is not properly synchronized with the databases. Try refreshing or updating the metastore to ensure it reflects the latest database changes.